# How can I change the values of a PySimpleGUI table?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, pysimplegui

I have been working with PySimpleGUI, where I'm trying to change from an initial empty table as presented in the figure 1, there can be observed how the initial table at the bottom is empty and has three columns.

*Figure 1:*

[image: Figure 1]

In here I use a script where you imput your databases, and click on -GENERATE- to apply some statistcs and present it as an image on the rigth side and a table with statistical data on the bottom.

Here you can see the script:

*Script (deleted irrelevant things):*

```
# TABLE DATA 

data= {
  ("Count", "-", "-"),
  ("Average", " -", "-"),
  ("Median", "-", "-"),
  ("Min", " -", "-"),
  ("Max", "-", "-"),
  ("StdDev", " -", "-"),
  ("Q1", "-", "-"),
  ("Q2", " -", "-"),
}

headings = ["STAT", "DATABASE A", "DATABASE B"] #list


# Table generation:
list_variables = ["Count", "Average", "Median", "Min", "Max", "StdDev", "Q1", "Q3"]
dicts = {}

def tablegen (imp_dict): #enter dictionary from -FOLDERS- 
        for k in imp_dict.items():
            del k[1]["survey"]
            v = [k[1].shape[0],np.average(k[1].iloc[:,0]) ,np.median(k[1].iloc[:,0]),min(k[1].iloc[:,0]),max(k[1].iloc[:,0]),np.std(k[1].iloc[:,0]),np.quantile(k[1].iloc[:,0],0.25),np.quantile(k[1].iloc[:,0],0.75)]
            final[k[0]]=v


#  LAYOUT

layout = [
        [sg.Button('GENERATE'),sg.Button('REMOVE')],
    
    [sg.Text('Generated table:')],
    [sg.Table(values=data, headings=headings, max_col_width=25, 
        auto_size_columns=True,
        display_row_numbers=False,
        justification='center',
        num_rows=5,
        alternating_row_color='lightblue',
        key='-TABLE-',
        selected_row_colors='red on yellow',
        enable_events=True,
        expand_x=False,
        expand_y=True,
        vertical_scroll_only=True,          
        tooltip='This is a table')]
]

window = sg.Window('Tool', layout)


# ------ Loops ------

while True:
    if event == 'GENERATE': #problems
        selection(file_list) #some functions blah blah, it generates a csv file called "minimum"

 #This is the archive (minimum.csv) that is produced after clicking -GENERATE- to make the desired table (it applies some functions).
        file_loc2 = (real_path + "/minimum.csv")

        try:
            archive = pd.read_csv(file_loc2, sep=",")
            df_names = pd.unique(archive["survey"]) #column names

            for name in df_names: #enter initial archive
                dicts[name] = pd.DataFrame(data= (archive.loc[archive["survey"] == name ]),columns=("Wavelength_(nm)", "survey")) #iteration blah blah
            tablegen(dicts) #this generates the statistical values for the table.
            final_df = pd.DataFrame(data= final, index=list_variables, columns=df_names)   
            final_df = final_df.round(decimals=1)
            final_lists = final_df.values.tolist()


# I tried using a DataFrame and produced the table in figure 2 (final_df), and a list of list (as recomended at PySimpleGUI webpage) final_lists and produced the table in figure 3.
            window["-TABLE-"].update(final_df) #or .update(final_lists)

        except Exception as E:
            print(f'** Error {E} **')
            pass        # if something weird happened making the full filename
  
window.close()
```

**The issue is this:**

In the second and third figures present how this script uses the information from the folders (databases) selected in the left square, and generates the image in the left and supposedly would present DataFrame shown below.

*GOAL TABLE TO PRESENT:*

```
final_df:
         13 MAR 2018  14 FEB 2018  16 FEB 2018  17 FEB 2018
Count           84.0         25.0         31.0         31.0
Average       2201.5       2202.1       2203.1       2202.9
Median        2201.0       2202.0       2204.0       2204.0
Min           2194.0       2197.0       2198.0       2198.0
Max           2208.0       2207.0       2209.0       2209.0
StdDev           4.0          3.0          3.5          3.5
Q1            2198.0       2199.0       2199.5       2199.5
Q3            2205.0       2205.0       2206.0       2206.0
```

*Figure 2:* This is using a DataFrame as imput in the loop -GENERATE-.

[image]

*Figure 3:* This is using a list of lists as imput in the loop -GENERATE-.

[image]

As it is observed, the "-TABLE-" is not working the way that I intend. If I use a DataFrame it is just selecting the columns names, and if I use a list of list it ignores the index and column names from the intended goal table.

Also, the table is in both cases not generating more columns even there should be 5 including the index. And how can I change the column names from the initially provided ones?

In the PySimpleGUI demos and call references I can not find something to solve this, also I searched in the web and in older StackOverflow posts, but to be honest I do not find a similar case to this.

I'll be really greatful if somebody can help me to find what I am doing wrong!

*Btw sorry for my english, Colombian here.*

Comment: your first exercise is to get matplotlib to render inside your gui

Comment: @rioV8 I was just trying to make everything understandable, have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of columns increased per records ? Most of time, the number of rows of a Table element increased per records. Maybe you should take `['Date'] + list_variables` as the headings of the Table element, and add each holder as one new row of the Table element.

```py
import pandas as pd
import PySimpleGUI as sg

file = r'd:/Qtable.csv'
"""
Date,Count,Average,Median,Min,Max,StdDev,Q1,Q3
13-Mar-18,84,2201.5,2201,2194,2208,4,2198,2205
14-Mar-18,25,2202.1,2202,2197,2207,3,2199,2205
16-Mar-18,31,2203.1,2204,2198,2209,3.5,2199.5,2206
17-Mar-18,31,2202.9,2204,2198,2209,3.5,2199.5,2206
"""

df       = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
values   = df.values.tolist()
headings = values[0]
data     = values[1:]

layout = [[sg.Table(data, headings=headings, key='-TABLE-')]]
sg.Window('Table', layout).read(close=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Ohh I did not think about that way to present the data, it will work! Thank you